# ASP.NET CORE authentication cookie disappears

Tags: angular, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

English is not first language, so if sounds weird please let me know :)

My development environments

```
Asp.net Core 2.2 && Angular 10.0
```

Currently, I have this problem for 3months now and still can't figure out what is solution.
so issue happened this time

```
> Mysite.com ----> **Survey.com ----> Mysite.com**
```

when users come back from 'Survey.com' to 'Mysite.com', randomly authentication cookie disappears.
below is part of 'Start.cs'. if every user lost their authentication cookie then I can clearly see what cause problem, but it's randomly happen even same PC(but if I able to re-login, it's not happen for a while and suddenly happen).

```
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        //Add indentity types
        services.AddIdentity<TUserName, TTesterRole>(config =>
        {
            config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            config.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            config.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            config.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            config.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            config.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
            config.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-.,/;'`!@#$%^&*()_+[]{}";
        })
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddTokenProvider<DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUserName>>("Default");

        // Identity Services
        services.AddTransient<IUserStore<TUserName>, PKRctUserDatastore>();
        services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<TTesterRole>, PKRctRoleDatastore>();
        services.AddTransient<PKRctDataTable>();

        // linq error logs
        services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => {
            loggingBuilder.AddConsole()
                .AddFilter(DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name, LogLevel.Information);
            loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
        });

        // protected token life
        services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(3);
        });

        // Add application services
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, MessageSender>();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddSignalR();

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });

        //// set cookies - Identity cookie setting
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
            options.Cookie.Name = "MYIDENTITY";
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(3);
            options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
```

Please help me!

Comment: Have you checked if you browser receives `Set-Cookie` header that expires the cookie? Or if simply your cookie expires by itself because it becomes too old?

Comment: @Xerillio Hi, I can see the cookie from my browser and even though cookie will expires 3 days later, sometimes it's just disappeared.. Do you think is because of token expired?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe try to set the expiration down to a few minutes and test what happens

Comment: @Xerillio I tried, and cookie removed after expiration time correctly.